# How can I make a good validation?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have some issues with validation. Even if validation is false, the form is still sending. Where is the problem?

```
function ValidateForm(form){
  ErrorText= "";
  if ( ( form.memory[0].checked == false ) && ( form.memory[1].checked == false )  && ( form.memory[2].checked == false ) ){
     alert ( "Please choose size of RAM memory" );
     return false;
  }
  if (ErrorText= "") { form.submit() }
  return false;
} 

<button type="submit" form="form" class="submit-button" onClick="ValidateForm(this.form)">Dodaj do koszyka</button>
```

Comment: You are not passing the return value of the function call on, as is necessary with this type of “old-school” event handling attached via HTML attributes. `onClick="return ValidateForm(this.form)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of a `type="submit"` button is to submit the form, to stop this you need to return false. Which your method is doing, but your `onClick` handler is ignoring

```
<button type="submit" form="form" class="submit-button" onClick="return ValidateForm(this.form)">Dodaj do koszyka</button>
------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^
```

Also, no need to call `form.submit()` in your method, this will happen if you just `return true` instead. So change

```
if (ErrorText= "") { form.submit() }
```

to

```
if (ErrorText == "") { return true; }
```

NOTE: You were missing a double equals `==` not `=`

Comment: So, how can I fix it ? When I putting onsubmit="return false" it is false in every case, yes ?

Comment: @BrainRails exactly as shown, add `return` inside the `onClick` attribute